# Requiring modules from inside imported classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have the following boilerplate express app:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Person = require('./controllers/person.js');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
})

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    var person = new Person('Bob', 'Smith');
    res.send(person.sayHello());
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Example app listening on port ' + 3000);
})
```

And my person.js file looks like this:

```js
module.exports = class Person {

   constructor(first, last) {
       this.first = first;
       this.last = last;
       this.sayHello();
   }


   sayHello() {
       return ('Hi, my name is ' + this.first + ' ' + this.last)
   }

}
```

Now this all works fine, but things break when I want to import modules that are just going to work on the person class.

For example, when if I change `Person.sayHello()` to:

```js
async sayHello() {
       var axios = require('axios')
       var response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
       return response.title
   }
```

The entire project refuses to serve requests. I have troubleshooted that the problem is the line where I require the new module, but I can't figure out another way to require that module just for that class?

Furthermore, the async isn't the issue here, if I change the `sayHello()` function to be:

```
sayHello() {
       var axios = require('axios')
       return 'This line is never returned';
}
```

The server still errors and a GET request gives me an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: Hmm, my asyncs a bit lacking atm, but maybe: `var person = new Person('Bob', 'Smith'); var title = await person.sayHello(); res.send(title);` You're immediately sending the response of sayHello without waiting for the axios request to resolve.

Comment: You are passing the result of `person.sayHello()` to `res.send`, however, because `sayHello` is an async function, you need to `then` or `await` it to get the result.

Comment: what do you mean "refuses to serve requests"? do you get an error? a timeout? what exactly?

Comment: try loading the person class outside of express app, eg make a simple test file which loads the person class and says hello (simply run it with node), what do you get there?

Comment: @NikosM. a POST to / returns 503.

Comment: So in your last iteration of the `sayHello` function in your question, if you remove the line requiring axios, it works? And your GET request in express is missing a `res.send()`.

Comment: That's correct @Callam

Comment: you have a javascript error somewhere maybe `axios` is not defined or cannot find the module or sth else, (this is what `503` status code means), try testing the person class directly outside express and see what error you get and fix it

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the result of `person.sayHello()` to `res.send`, however, because `sayHello` is an async function, you need to `then` or `await` it to get the result of the Promise. The functions also called in your `Person` constructor, without executing the Promise. I presume it is reduntant since you're calling the function in your express app after initiating a person.

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const person = new Person('Bob', 'Smith');

  try {
    res.send(await person.sayHello());
  } catch(error) {
    res.send(error.message || `${error}`);
  }
});
```

You will also find that the response from axios doesn't have a `title` property, you need can access it by `response.data.title`.

```
module.exports = class Person {
  constructor(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
  }

  async sayHello() {
    const axios = require('axios');
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
    );

    return response.data.title;
  }
}
```

Not sure if you have removed the implementation of your get request in the express app from the question or if you don't actually have one yet. If that's the case, it will timeout on a GET request to /.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Person = require('./controllers/person.js');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, World!');
})

app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const person = new Person('Bob', 'Smith');
  res.send(await person.sayHello());
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port ' + 3000);
})
```

Anyway, using the two previous blocks of code, I was able to succeed in requiring axios inside the `sayHello` function and return the title of the response data. I cannot however reproduce the problem you're describing, with the exception of the timeout as a result of the empty route.

Comment: I should have been more specific, I have tried this too, but my problem is that when I call this function the entire express server shuts down and gives me a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, the async part isn't relevant to this particular issue, it's the line that requires the node dynamically inside the function that causes the error.

Comment: Do you require the module to be required inside the function? And does it work when you don't require it inside the function.

Comment: Well I put it there in the question because it seems the most likely place for it to go, however when I include it anywhere in the child class it fails.

Comment: What happens if you declare and require axios outside the class, at the top of the file above `module.exports`?

Comment: Then the response from my server is empty.